# Konsole like terminal for Gnome

Tags: gnome, gnome-terminal, search, konsole

I would like to switch from Kubuntu to Ubuntu but so far I couldn't find a terminal emulator for Gnome which had history support like Konsole does. In Konsole you can set the history to be unlimited and you can have *highlighted search* results almost instantly.

Is there such a terminal emulator which would provide the same features in Gnome?
This would be very essential for me.

Comment: Why not use Konsole in Unity?

Comment: Well that's exactly what I'm trying to avoid. I wouldn't want to pull in half of KDE just for Konsole.

Comment: Well, 68MB on 12.10 and 140MB after install... Besides that is half ways for getting kate also ;) (I do know that one does not want to install all of that just for konsole, just teasing a bit). Dont forget to mark any solutions bellow as an answer if they work for you.

Answer (score 3):

For unlimited history, you'll have to edit `~/.bashrc`. The default configuration is as

```
# for setting history length see HISTSIZE and HISTFILESIZE in bash(1)
HISTSIZE=1000
HISTFILESIZE=2000
```

You can edit above variables to a large number for unlimited history.

Also, you can use `konsole` itself in unity. To install,

```
sudo apt-get install konsole
```

Comment: That's neat. Didn't know that you can configure bash to keep more. Is it possible also to enable some instant highlight feature in Terminator or something similar? See [example](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/37/konsolehighlight.png/)

Comment: I think the feature he is looking for is the text search in the scrollback. The shell histoty contains only very few lines of that.